# Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error when I tried to refresh url with new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error when running the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url ="http://localhost/php/ifsccode.php";

    $("#bank").change(function() {
        var bank =$( "#bank" ).val();
        window.location = url+"/"+bank+"/";
    });

});
```

If I change the `var url ="http://localhost/php/ifsccode.php";` value to 
`var url ="http://localhost/php/ifsccode.php?";` then it's working.

But I don't want to add the `?` mark.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are setting the `window.location` to `http:…/ifsccode.php/.../`, so your URL does not end in `.php` but has `.php` somewhere in the middle. So your server will not execute it as PHP code. Are you expecting that it should?

Comment: I solved the issue. I didn't given full path of Js file.